# Converting a string of text into alternate representations (binary, hex, ascii)

Tags: java

In Java, is there a simple method to convert the format of a given string?  For example, I have the string "test22".  I'd like the binary value and hex value.  As well as possibly the ascii values of each character?

Comment: Hex of what? 22? The UTF-16 characters of the string? The UTF-8 characters of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to take the String, convert it to a char array, and then convert the integer values of the char array into binary or hex through the [Integer.toBinaryString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) or [Integer.toHexString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)) or [Integer.toOctalString()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString(int)) if you would like.

just replace binary string with hex and the function will do the same thing

```
public String convertToBinary(String str){
    char [] array = str.toCharArray();
    String binaryToBeReturned = "";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        binaryToBeReturned += Integer.toBinaryString((int)array[i]) + " ";
    }

    return binaryToBeReturned;

}
```

Also to get the ASCII values of the String `int value = (int)string.charAt(i);` will get the ASCII value.

I added a space just for formatting, not sure how you needed it formatted, and this is just a simple implementation.